# Google maps dynamic ajaxed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to work with google maps.

I've loaded the markers from my data base and plotted on map, but now I am trying to load a side bar with visible markers on screen

How can i do that its like an IDX / MLS but i would like to create my own, i dont want to use the webservices just want to add my data into maps and markers.

reference maps are: [maps reference](http://idx.diversesolutions.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you run a simple databse query to retrieve the markers that fall within the current bounding box of the map.
 You can get the bounding box as follows:

```
var bounds=map.getBounds();
var southwest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northeast = bounds.getNorthEast();
```

write an ajax query that qill send `southWest.lat()`, `southWest.lnt()`, `northeast.lat()`, `northeast.lng()` and then write a dB query with these parameters and send the result back.

Hope this is what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks Baz1nga for prompt reply and for the suggestion.